# Web Scraping Node.js in DOM page

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cheerio

I want to get information from the [site](http://s.new-rutor.org/torrent/562313/afera-po-anglijski_trespass-against-us-2016-hdrip-ot-megapeer-p/) using Node.js 
I tryied so hard, and ̶g̶o̶t̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶f̶a̶r̶ . So, I want to get  a magnet URI link, this link is in:

```
<div id="download"> 
<a href=magnet:?xt=urn:btih:335fc3d9d870109a8dd0e87765a9210754dd8fac&amp;dn=rutor.org_%D0%90%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8+%2F+Trespass+Against+Us+%282016%29+HDRip+%D0%BE%D1%82+MegaPeer+%7C+P&amp;tr=udp://opentor.org:2710&amp;tr=udp://opentor.org:2710&amp;tr=retracker.local/announce"><img src="/parse/s.rutor.org/i/magnet.gif"></a>
```

How to get this link from div and href field using cheerio. I dont know how to jQuery, I just want to write an parser.

Here is my try:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('http://s.new-rutor.org/torrent/562496/povorot-ne-tuda-5-krovnoe-rodstvo_wrong-turn-5-bloodlines-2012-bdrip-avc-p/', function(err, resp, body) {
        if (!err){
          const $ = cheerio.load(body);
           var magnet = $('.href', '#downloads').text()
         // $('#downloads').find('href').text()

          console.log(magnet); 
      }
});
```

That code is only getting empty place in console

Comment: for starters you are console logging body instead of $('.href', '#downloads').text()

Comment: @Glutch, thanks I added a variable but, there is empty(no text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I'm using request-promise instead of request

This code console.logs all a-tags with a href that contains 'magnet'

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('http://s.new-rutor.org/torrent/562496/povorot-ne-tuda-5-krovnoe-rodstvo_wrong-turn-5-bloodlines-2012-bdrip-avc-p/').then(res => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(res)
  const links = $('a')
  links.each(i => {
    const link = links.eq(i).attr('href')
    if (link && link.includes('magnet')) {
      console.log(link)
    }
  })
})
```

eq selects a specific link from that index

```
links.each(i => links.eq(i))
```

then we grab the content inside the attribute href (the magnet link) with

```
links.eq(i).attr('href')
```